# Run when modal is inserted in the DOM

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using the animated Twitter Bootstrap's Modal component and I would like to manipulate its elements as soon as they're available in the DOM.

To clarify, I don't have the modal waiting in the DOM, I'm compiling a Handlebars template and calling `.modal()` upon it, otherwise I would be able to manipulate it simply when the DOM is ready.

Bootstrap exposes 2 relevant events, `show.bs.modal` and `shown.bs.modal`. The former is triggered when the modal is toggled, but **before** it's inserted in the DOM, and the latter is triggered after the modal finishes displaying, but this is **after** the display animation is finished, which is too late and causes a FOUC. The `.modal()` method inserts the modal in the DOM at some point, but when I tried searching for it right after calling that method, it wasn't there.

I figured out that manipulating it after 200ms works, but it feels dirty and I'm not sure it will always work. How can I manipulate it after the modal is inserted in the DOM, but before the animation starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, `.modal()` does not insert the modal into the DOM. It does insert a `.modal-backdrop` into the DOM, but not the modal itself.

Seems like you should be able to just:

1. Compile the template
2. Insert the resulting modal HTML into the DOM. (The modal will be `display: none` by default, so this is safe.)
3. Perform your manipulations of the modal's elements
4. Call `.modal()`

Comment: Such a simple solution, thanks! Yes `.modal()` indeed does insert the HTML in the DOM if it isn't inserted before, I'm just not sure when.